# Drupal 7 : problem with newly added field language property

Tags: entities

I have to add some new field to a content type on a Drupal 7 site.

The new fields works perfectly, but when I'm saving my node, those fields language property is set to "und", while all the olders fields language is set to "en".

Why is there a difference with the newly added field ?

How can I manage to set the language of my new field to "en" ?

This cause me some trouble with existing module which use the language property.

Thank you in advance.